# SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ProfileServlet] in context with path [/Homework] threw exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, servlets

I'm getting this exception and i have no idea why. It says its a number format exception is null. I have looked at other posts about this but none of them fixes my problem. My profile class is a simple class that has id username lastname age and favTeam with setters and getters and a constructor. Anyone know why this is happening?

My Servlet

```
public ProfileServlet() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
HashMap<Integer, Profile> team = new HashMap<Integer, Profile>();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    //String requestUrl = request.getRequestURI();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

    Profile test = new Profile();
    int id;

    test = team.get(id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID")));

    if(test != null)
    {
        out.println("ID: " + test.getId());
        out.println("name: " + test.getUsername());
        out.println("lastname: " + test.getLastname());
        out.println("age: " + test.getAge());
        out.println("favTeam: " + test.getFavTeam());
    }
    else
    {
        //ERROR

    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String age  = request.getParameter("id");

    int x = 0;
    if(id!=null){
      try{
        x = Integer.parseInt(id);
       }catch(Exception e){
       }

    }

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String favTeam = request.getParameter("favTeam");

    int numage = 0;
    if(id!=null){
      try{
        numage = Integer.parseInt(age);
       }catch(Exception e){
       }

    }

    Profile profile = new Profile(x,username,lastname,favTeam,numage);

    team.put(profile.getId(),profile);

}

}
```

My .xml

```
 <display-name>Homework</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProfileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ntrut.ProfileServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ProfileServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/profile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  </web-app>
```

Comment: can you add error stacktrace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error seems in your below line.

```
Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"))
```

Make sure value returned from `request.getParameter("ID")` is a Number,

Can you try to print value of `request.getParameter("ID")` before this line ? you will see it is not a number value.

Answer (score 0):

What i did to fix my issue is what i did in my doPost. I had to do the same thing in my doGet with the request.getParameter

```
 String id = request.getParameter("id");

    int x = 0;
    if(id!=null){
      try{
        x = Integer.parseInt(id);
       }catch(Exception e){
       }

    }

    test = team.get(x);
```

Comment: its not idle way to just surround in try catch and not doing anything in catch. you need to make sure request.getParameter("id") must return number value